# Error while running simple ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

playbook is as below...

```
[ansible@ansible2 outline]$ cat webserver.yaml

--- #Create an YAML from an outline


  - hosts: web
    connection: ssh
    remote_user: ansible
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
    gather_facts: yes

    vars:
      test: raju
    vars_files:
        - /home/ansible/playbooks/conf/copyright.yaml

    vars_prompt:
     - name: web_domain
       prompt: WEB DOMAIN

    tasks:
    - name: install apache web server
      yum: pkg=httpd state=latest
      notify: start the service

    - name: check service
      command: service httpd status
      register: result
    - debug: var=result

    handlers:
    - name: start the service
      service: name=httpd state=restarted

[ansible@ansible2 outline]$
```

and the error as below...

```
[ansible@ansible2 outline]$ ansible-playbook webserver.yaml
WEB DOMAIN:

PLAY [web] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************

ok: [web2.bharathkumarraju.com]

TASK [install apache web server] ***********************************************

changed: [web2.bharathkumarraju.com]

TASK [check service] ***********************************************************
fatal: [web2.bharathkumarraju.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["service", "httpd", "status"], "delta": "0:00:00.039489", "end": "2016-10-30 04:53:51.833760", "failed": true, "rc": 3, "start": "2016-10-30 04:53:51.794271", "stderr": "", "stdout": "httpd is stopped", "stdout_lines": ["httpd is stopped"], "warnings": ["Consider using service module rather than running service"]}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

RUNNING HANDLER [start the service] ********************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/outline/webserver.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
web2.bharathkumarraju.com  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: what version ansible are you using?

Comment: [ansible@ansible2 outline]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.2.0
  config file = /home/ansible/tests/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try check service's status using `/etc/init.d`

```
- name: check service
  stat: path=/etc/init.d/httpd
  register: result
```

Comment: tasks:
    - name: install apache web server
      yum: pkg=httpd state=latest
      notify: start the service

    - name: check service
#      command:  service httpd status
      stat: path=/etc/init.d/httpd
      register: result
    - debug: var=result

    handlers:
    - name: start the service
      service: name=httpd state=restarted

Comment: this is like linux stat command right...
It will ensure that the file present ....

[root@web2 ansible]# stat /etc/init.d/httpd
  File: `/etc/init.d/httpd'
  Size: 3488            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 143438      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-10-30 06:30:53.092051135 +0000
Modify: 2016-07-18 15:24:35.000000000 +0000
Change: 2016-10-30 06:30:52.701051135 +0000

Answer (score 2):

The exit code of running service httpd status is different then 0 because the service was not started. Handlers are always ran at the end of a playbook not when they are notified.

One solution is to put an "ignore_errors: true" at the check service status. Another solution would be to remove the handler+notify and put a service module after the yum:

```
- service: name=httpd status=started enabled=yes
```

Comment: thanks a lot but how can we ensure that the service installed successfully

Comment: Using yum module, if it were to have an issue for example proxy is not working or some dependency is required but not found, yum would fail and thus ansible would fail at that step. The fact that it didn't fail at yum module tells you that the package was installed correctly. So don't worry about yum not doing it's job :)